# Error Connecting VSTS to AAD

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We are trying to connect our existing VSTS account to AAD following the instructions at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/connect-account-to-aad?view=vsts

When we try to perform the step at: 'Connect your VSTS account to your organization directory' #6, we receive the following error:

Account ****** connection to an AAD Tenant failed due to the error : Account entitlement not found in the dictionary for source identity 'dffde1b5-5781-4c53-bbb2-5ff5792383dc'.

We have tried this with 2 separate MSA accounts; one was existing, one we create from scratch. The MSA accounts are added as a guest to AAD.  We have made it owner on the subscription, is there a permission that I am missing?

One answer said they just had to wait 12 hours, we have waited 24 with no change.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Hopefully this helps:
Request is to: 
PATCH https://peprodscussu2.portalext.visualstudio.com/_apis/AzureTfs/Account/b7615ac7-c2f6-466c-9f73-b8ed37258259?tenantId=f1295c9e-6264-403f-a42b-5be8fd3266fa HTTP/1.1

Response shows 500 Internal Server Error: 
`{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Account entitlement not found in the dictionary for source identity 'dffde1b5-5781-4c53-bbb2-5ff5792383dc'.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Licensing.TransferUserLicenseException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"TransferUserLicenseException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`

Let me know if there is additional information from Fiddler that you need.

Comment: Can you provide the fiddler trace for the error?

Comment: Hopefully this is what you are looking for:

Comment: You have to submit a VSTS Technical Support Ticket for this issue: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was on Microsoft's end. Apparently there was duplicate orphaned user entries for a user that had been deleted 3 years ago from the VSTS account. They had to manually correct it.  Thanks for your help.